# Print out each step of recursion

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

I'm using Erlang shell to test out the language, and I've wrote a sum function two ways: one a more classical recursive sum and the other using tail recursion. The second one is meant to be linear, and the first grows with the size of input.

How can I see each step of the recursion? I want it to print out the current value at each step so I can better understand what is happening.

Here are my two functions:

Normal Recursion:

```
sum([]) -> 0;
sum([H|T]) -> H + sum(T).
```

Tail recursion:

```
tail_sum(List) -> tail_sum(List, 0).
tail_sum([], Sum) -> Sum;
tail_sum([H|T], Sum) -> tail_sum(T, H+Sum).
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `dbg` module in Erlang provides a useful feature for this: tracing. Here's how you'd trace these functions assuming your code is in the module `a`:

Setup:

```
1> c(a). % load a.erl
{ok,a}
2> dbg:tracer(). % start the default trace message receiver
{ok,<0.71.0>}
3> dbg:p(all, c). % setup call tracing on all processes
{ok,[{matched,nonode@nohost,34}]}
4> dbg:tpl(a, '_', '_', []). % trace all functions in a
{ok,[{matched,nonode@nohost,5}]}
```

Now whenever you call any function in the module, its name and arguments will be printed in the shell.

```
5> a:sum(lists:seq(1, 10)).
(<0.64.0>) call a:sum([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
(<0.64.0>) call a:sum([2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
(<0.64.0>) call a:sum([3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
(<0.64.0>) call a:sum([4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
(<0.64.0>) call a:sum([5,6,7,8,9,10])
(<0.64.0>) call a:sum([6,7,8,9,10])
(<0.64.0>) call a:sum([7,8,9,10])
(<0.64.0>) call a:sum("\b\t\n")
(<0.64.0>) call a:sum("\t\n")
(<0.64.0>) call a:sum("\n")
(<0.64.0>) call a:sum([])
55
6> a:tail_sum(lists:seq(1, 10)).
(<0.64.0>) call a:tail_sum([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
(<0.64.0>) call a:tail_sum([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],0)
(<0.64.0>) call a:tail_sum([2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],1)
(<0.64.0>) call a:tail_sum([3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],3)
(<0.64.0>) call a:tail_sum([4,5,6,7,8,9,10],6)
(<0.64.0>) call a:tail_sum([5,6,7,8,9,10],10)
(<0.64.0>) call a:tail_sum([6,7,8,9,10],15)
(<0.64.0>) call a:tail_sum([7,8,9,10],21)
(<0.64.0>) call a:tail_sum("\b\t\n",28)
(<0.64.0>) call a:tail_sum("\t\n",36)
(<0.64.0>) call a:tail_sum("\n",45)
(<0.64.0>) call a:tail_sum([],55)
55
```

You can also ask the tracer to log the returned values using a match spec which returns `return_trace()`. This clearly shows how `sum` incrementally builds up the value in contrast to `tail_sum`:

```
7> dbg:tpl(a, '_', '_', [{'_',[],[{return_trace}]}]).
(<0.64.0>) call a:module_info()
{ok,[{matched,nonode@nohost,5},{saved,1}]}
8> a:sum(lists:seq(1, 10)).
(<0.64.0>) call a:sum([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
(<0.64.0>) call a:sum([2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
(<0.64.0>) call a:sum([3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
(<0.64.0>) call a:sum([4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
(<0.64.0>) call a:sum([5,6,7,8,9,10])
(<0.64.0>) call a:sum([6,7,8,9,10])
(<0.64.0>) call a:sum([7,8,9,10])
(<0.64.0>) call a:sum("\b\t\n")
(<0.64.0>) call a:sum("\t\n")
(<0.64.0>) call a:sum("\n")
(<0.64.0>) call a:sum([])
(<0.64.0>) returned from a:sum/1 -> 0
(<0.64.0>) returned from a:sum/1 -> 10
(<0.64.0>) returned from a:sum/1 -> 19
(<0.64.0>) returned from a:sum/1 -> 27
(<0.64.0>) returned from a:sum/1 -> 34
(<0.64.0>) returned from a:sum/1 -> 40
(<0.64.0>) returned from a:sum/1 -> 45
(<0.64.0>) returned from a:sum/1 -> 49
(<0.64.0>) returned from a:sum/1 -> 52
(<0.64.0>) returned from a:sum/1 -> 54
(<0.64.0>) returned from a:sum/1 -> 55
55
9> a:tail_sum(lists:seq(1, 10)).
(<0.64.0>) call a:tail_sum([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
(<0.64.0>) call a:tail_sum([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],0)
(<0.64.0>) call a:tail_sum([2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],1)
(<0.64.0>) call a:tail_sum([3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],3)
(<0.64.0>) call a:tail_sum([4,5,6,7,8,9,10],6)
(<0.64.0>) call a:tail_sum([5,6,7,8,9,10],10)
(<0.64.0>) call a:tail_sum([6,7,8,9,10],15)
(<0.64.0>) call a:tail_sum([7,8,9,10],21)
(<0.64.0>) call a:tail_sum("\b\t\n",28)
(<0.64.0>) call a:tail_sum("\t\n",36)
(<0.64.0>) call a:tail_sum("\n",45)
(<0.64.0>) call a:tail_sum([],55)
(<0.64.0>) returned from a:tail_sum/2 -> 55
(<0.64.0>) returned from a:tail_sum/2 -> 55
(<0.64.0>) returned from a:tail_sum/2 -> 55
(<0.64.0>) returned from a:tail_sum/2 -> 55
(<0.64.0>) returned from a:tail_sum/2 -> 55
(<0.64.0>) returned from a:tail_sum/2 -> 55
(<0.64.0>) returned from a:tail_sum/2 -> 55
(<0.64.0>) returned from a:tail_sum/2 -> 55
(<0.64.0>) returned from a:tail_sum/2 -> 55
(<0.64.0>) returned from a:tail_sum/2 -> 55
(<0.64.0>) returned from a:tail_sum/2 -> 55
(<0.64.0>) returned from a:tail_sum/1 -> 55
55
```

Comment: I just edited my answer to include `return_trace`. This should be even more useful for you. Tracing is one of my favorite feature of the Erlang VM!